# Posting a Params Request to PHP Heroku Server From iOS

Tags: php, ios, heroku, token, stripe-payments

I'm trying to POST a token to a PHP file (https://thawing-inlet-46474.herokuapp.com/charge.php) from Alamofire in iOS, but Stripe doesn't show any completed charges. This is the exact PHP file:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_qCTa2pcFZ9wG6jEvPGY7tLOK");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token =  $_POST['stripeToken'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$currency = $_POST['currency'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount*100, // Convert amount in cents to dollar
    "currency" => $currency,
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => $description)
    );

    // Check that it was paid:
    if ($charge->paid == true) {
        $response = array( 'status'=> 'Success', 'message'=>'Payment has been charged!!' );
    } else { // Charge was not paid!
        $response = array( 'status'=> 'Failure', 'message'=>'Your payment could NOT be processed because the payment system rejected the transaction. You can try again or use another card.' );
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

And this is the code from Swift:

```
func postToken(token:STPToken) {

    let parameters : [ String : AnyObject] = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId, "amount": 10000, "currency": "usd", "description": "testRun"]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://thawing-inlet-46474.herokuapp.com/charge.php", parameters: parameters).responseString { (response) in

        print(response)

    }

}
```

The token is being created for sure and the response after posting to Heroku is SUCCESS: followed by blank space.. Anyone have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: 1/ Catch **all** errors and not just the card ones. 2/ Look into your logs in the dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs. 3/ Look into your error log on your server. 99% sure you're using the wrong API key in your iOS application which is the most common error.

Comment: Thanks! In addition to changing the params type I actually did need to change the API Key.

Answer (score 0):

Two things fixed this issue:

Changing the API key in my PHP file to the correct key, and adjusting the "amount" type from an Integer to a String:

```
func postToken(token:STPToken) {

    let requestString = "https://thawing-inlet-46474.herokuapp.com/charge.php"
    let params = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId, "amount": "200", "currency": "usd", "description": "testRun"]

    //POST request (simple)
    //Alamofire.request(.POST, requestString, parameters: params)

    //POST request (with handler)
    Alamofire.request(.POST, requestString, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
            }
    }

}
```